# implementing similar classes (data entity objects)

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am working on an application which currently creates data entity objects from the results of a sql query. In the database 3 of the tables are very similar but have several different properties.

My initial plan was to create 3 different classes, even though each class is very similar. However when I came to create the method which returns a list of objects, I have hit a stumbling block as the return type will be different depending on which mode the application is in.

e.g.

```
public class A
{
   public int Id {get;}
   public string Name {get;}
}

 public class B
 {
   public int Id {get;}
   public string Name {get;}
   public string ExtraInfo {get;}
 }


 public class MainScreen
 {
     ...
     this.resultsGrid.DataSource = LoadData();
 }
```

I would prefer not to write one method to load a list of each data type.
What should the return type of LoadData() be, to allow it to be generic as possible.

What is the most elegant way of dealing with this scenario?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Could you elaborate on the entities and application's general purpose? Will help determining which approach suits you best.

Comment: the entities are transactions which depending on the type use one of the three tables and have different properties. The application is only displaying data so business logic is not essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have inheritance to allow polymorphism, so you would have a base class that all entities included in the data binding derive from it.

Then, you can have a mid-base class to have some shared properties like Name and ID.

Base class:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
}
```

Entity with Name and ID:

```
public class NameAndIDEntity : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Entity with Name, ID and ExtraInfo:

```
public class NameIDAndExtraEntity : NameAndIDEntity
{
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Entity with other information (can't be derived from NameAndIDEntity), derives from Entity so it can be included in the data binding:

```
public class OtherInformationEntity : Entity
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, you can make the LoadData return type Entity.

Comment: It's a good solution, but it is an overkill for what the poster wants to do. Judging from his code, he wants to display the same information in the list (possible, two columns `id` and `name`) for the different objects. I've posted an answer suggesting that he creates specialised classes that address UI concerns instead of trying to fit his domain classes in the UI.

Comment: If you're going there, might as well do it right all the way and have a repository and a BL.

Comment: It doesn't seem like he even needs these. He's instantiating these objects directly from data retrieved via SQL. I think he's trying to fit the type of records in appropriate classes although he's using them only for UI. If he was going to apply complex business logic to the objects, I'd recommend a BL. But, in any case, BL and UI are different concerns best served by separate classes.

Comment: I can't think of an application that deals with SQL, entities with ID's etc, and without any business logic. And for the record - doesn't have to be complex. UI should do NOTHING more than UI logic.

Comment: I can: reports. Yes, you're right, UI should do nothing more than UI logic... with UI classes :-)

Comment: I tried the approach above and because I am binding the list of base classes to a grid, which then uses reflection to display the information, all of the additional properties are being lost. Would it be possible to use an interface for the common properties and cast the list of interfaces to the correct type before binding?

Comment: @jeyound UI help-classes shouldn't be part of the UI. They are actually view models and are sitting in a layer between the BL and the UI.

Comment: @53AN You can have an abstract method GetData and implement in derived classes (3rd one calling base.GetData for the NameAndIDEntity implementation, and then adding it's own data - ExtraInfo). Use the method on each boxed Entity and you have yourself a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simples!

Create a class `ListItem` (with properties `Id` and `Name`, I presume). In your factory class/method, make instances of that class from the records into a `List` and bind the datasource to the list.

Don't be scared to create specialised classes for your UI.

**UPDATE:** Forgot to mention. Avoid inheritance as much as possible.

Comment: Nice solution, except for the UPDATE note. Why on earth aboiding inheritance? Inheritance is SUPERB, in every single way I can think of.

Comment: IMO, inheritance is the most misunderstood aspect of OOP. It is taught at the very start of a course, whereas it is a powerful tool to be used in expert hands only. Interestingly, inheritance isn't even a "first class" feature of OO; it is just one of the different types of relationship (the others being association, aggregation, composition). Abstraction, encapsulation, and polymorphism are more important characteristics of OO, but why inheritance came to such prominence, I don't know.

Comment: Because it helps polymorphism. encapsulation and abstraction, perhaps?

Comment: It is essential for polymorphism, but not for encapsulation and abstraction. What I meant is, it's sad that OOP became almost synonymous to inheritance when encapsulation and abstraction are more important characteristics.

Comment: I don't think it is right to say "more important". They are all equally needed for OOP, and create, together, the whole concept. I agree that inheritance is overused as OOP associations, but that doesn't mean you should avoid it. That's like saying that comedy movies are usually about love, so you should avoid watching comedy movies about love. (Hipstermuch?)

Answer (score -1):

First you can create an inheitance tree in your project, where base class holds a shared/common properties among set of dfferent types

Second you can retrieve from the query anonymous type and after map it to a known type by mapping them to a *real* type, like from Jon Skeet's blog [Horrible grotty hack: returning an anonymous type instance](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx)

That means that you need by the way know which query what type returns (can not avoid that), but this can reduce amount of fraction you need to add to your code, like from example:

```
static class GrottyHacks
{
    internal static T Cast<T>(object target, T example) //CAST TO SPECIFIED TYPE
    {
        return (T) target;
    }
}

class CheesecakeFactory
{
    static object CreateCheesecake()
    {
        return new { Fruit="Strawberry", Topping="Chocolate" };
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        object weaklyTyped = CreateCheesecake(); //ANONYMOUS TYPE GENERATION
        var stronglyTyped = GrottyHacks.Cast(weaklyTyped,
            new { Fruit="", Topping="" }); //"MAPPING"

        Console.WriteLine("Cheesecake: {0} ({1})",
            stronglyTyped.Fruit, stronglyTyped.Topping);            
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a reason its called a horrible grotty hack. It's really not OOP-y and opens up room for tones of errors and faults. It's just bad design. Why not make a class that holds Fruit and Topping? Anonymous types should VERY RARELY be used, and even then - in a closed, small scope.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I don't think it's a soooooo BAD design, honestly. You define a a single SQL query composer that returns a `data`(concept), and the caller by knowing what it quieried for just mappes (it's not a cast) to a real type. It's just like using a any available DB mapper out there. Absolutely not agree with this downvote. You can not have a flexibility (cause this is what asked by OP) and total control over situation.

Comment: Never count on the outside to "know" things except for the name of the method and it's parameters, because that really is all they actually "know". DB Mappers don't map to anonymous types - which is good and the right way to do it. It's only logical to have a class or a struct to hold that information and data.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: well, I would definitely prefer this dynamic, clean solution then overkill architecture, to make my types stay in the cage. I refer, naturally, to *this specific* question. The type safity benefits are out of doubt.

Comment: Understandable in this case. I'm just naturally a perfectionist, so even the tiniest project must be done flawlessly.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: that is *exact* point, if I can avoid grotesque architecture without paying too much in terms of type security and scallability of the project, it's better to choice something light and concise that does elegantly *exactly* what I need..

Comment: Just note that if your project expands, I strongly recommend that you change that design first.